# heightForRowAtIndexPath Not working properly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I am trying to display an image with a correct aspect ratio in my tableView. I have pre-calculated the aspect ratio of the image, and it seems to work properly on the actual image, but not on the cell it is displayed in.

Code for image in cell:

```
private var cellImage: UIImage? {
        get { return cellImageView.image }
        set {
            cellImageView?.image = newValue
            if let newimage = newValue {
                heightConstraint.constant = newimage.size.width / CGFloat(aspectRatio)
            }
        }
    }
```

Code in tableView:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return tableView.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(aspectRatio)
    }
```

aspectRatio is a variable that is the same in both. aspectRation = width/height of image. Also, I checked to see that the height received in both places is the same, and they are the same value (in runtime).

Anyone know why the cell height is not set correctly?

Comment: You have to add more details. Start by checking the console maybe you have autolayout conflicts.

Comment: Is every picture the same size?

Comment: You should use dynamic tableView cell heights when autolayout constraints are involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic cell height and make cell fit to imageView inside it
Check this tutorial
https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, the problem is fixed. Here is the solution I found:

I removed the calculation of the height constraint for the cellImage, and instead added an autolayout constraint of the image view to the bottom margin of the cell.
This fixed the problem.